# Enide Studio debug, always get "Nodeclipse/chromedevtools failed to connect to Standalone V8 VM"

Tags: node.js

I'm on Windows 7 64bit, I followed the instruction in this link http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ to set up Enide Studio

1. install latest nodejs, version=0.12.2
2. install Nodeclipse CLI and Express via npm install -g command
3. install JDK 8u45 64bit
4. download Enide Studio 2014.17-u2 for Windows x64

As said in this guide,

> That is enough for Node.js, JavaScript and Java development.

Then I follow this video http://www.nodeclipse.org/video, and just create one simplest "Node.js Express Project", when I try to right click app.js and debug it as node application, I always get "Nodeclipse/chromedevtools failed to connect to Standalone V8 VM".

If i right click app.js and run it, there's no problem. I can access it via http://localhost:3000

Is there any configuration I can do? thanks.